# Live update with Apache Jena

Tags: insert, jena

I have a requirement wherein I need to make realtime updates to my ontological data (in Jena) (Around 30 inserts/updates per minute)
I wanted to know if Jena is good for excessive updates.
Also, if not, Is there any other semantic web based technology which supports excessive updates?

Also, if I want to insert lot of resources in my model, is there any way to automatically (sequentially) generate URIs for the new resources?

Answer (score 0):

I can't for certain - it may well work for you.  It'll depend on the amount of data in an update, the storage system used and the capabilities of the machine.

There is no server side automatic generation of resources names.  The Jena library contains a URN UUID generator (for type V1 UUIDs) and Java provides type V4.  This can help you generate unique names in the application.